# UCanAccess/Jackcess Create View/Save Query in Access

Tags: java, ms-access, ucanaccess, jackcess

In Access you can save queries in a view. 
In my Java project I use UCanAccess with the underlying Jackcess library.
The normal SQL Statement `CREATE VIEW <name> AS <Select Statement>` is not supported by UCanAccess at the moment and I don't know when it will support it.

Can Jackcess perform the equivalent of `CREATE VIEW`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Jackcess can retrieve the SQL string of an existing saved query but it cannot create new ones.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if this is planned or is it just not possible? OR is there any other library which can do this?

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say it's "not possible" but it is not a feature that is in high demand. You could submit a [feature request for Jackcess](https://sourceforge.net/p/jackcess/feature-requests/) and if it gets implemented then UCanAccess DDL could probably be extended to support `CREATE VIEW`.

Comment: As far as i can tell, executing a "create view" in access just creates a query object.  it's certainly possible to populate the query table using jackcess, although converting a query string to the relevant rows would be a bit of work.